# Docker use system python package

Tags: python, docker, pip

How do I keep pip from compiling `av`, if I have `python3-av` installed through `apt`?

I'm performing a multi-arch Docker build with a Dockerfile that looks like this:

```
FROM python:3-bullseye
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y python3-av
COPY requirements.txt ./
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt
```

One of the requirements (`auto-editor`) requires `av`.
On ARM64 it attempts to *build `av` from source*, which takes more than 10 minutes.
How do I keep `pip` from installing `av` anew?

Answer (score 0):

As I understand, you want to make a check point after first install right?

You may separate this dockerfile into a baseimage.dockerfile and installation.dockerfile.

For baseimage.dockerfile

`FROM python:3-bullseye RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y python3-av`

Then, you build with
`docker build ./baseimage.dockerfile -t python-av-base`

This will allow you to make a checkpoint

For installation.dockerfile, run installation as you expect
`FROM python-av-base COPY requirements.txt ./ RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt`